# Javascript working even turned off in browser?

Tags: jquery

I came across this site http://manueg.okkernoot.net There is a jquery slider in the upper part of screen - welcome, services, project. However, when I turn javascript off in my browser and reload the page, it works as well. What it behind this, Can anyone explain a little bit? Thank you very much.

Comment: What slider are you talking about?

Comment: No; they are not running Javascript.

Comment: css can do cool things too.

Comment: I mean the box under Welcome. If you click on welcome, project or services even if javacsript is turned off,the box changes its contents. Is it pure css?

Comment: The styling of menu is done by CSS, not JavaScript, by using `:hover` pseudo-classes. The currently active page, again, is decorated by CSS means - the corresponding element in menu is given `'active'` class. Actually, this question looks more like a promo-item than as a real question. )

Comment: That's a tab panel, not a slider

Comment: There's JS to make it fade, but even that could be done with CSS animations. Notice that when you turn it off, there's no fading

Comment: @raina77ow thank you for explaining, as for promo, I thing the page is about the slider which is situated undet the box I was asking. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JuanMendes Is it css3 or css2 is enough?

Comment: CSS 3. See http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl-fade-in-out-css3.htm#fadingin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting. I wasn't aware of that but it seems that browser it self will scroll parent element to show selected inner element.

For example here we have a parent element with "tabscontent" id and then we have 3 inner element per each page. "welcome", "services" and "projects". When you change the page to "xx.html#services", browser will scroll "tabscontent" element to show desired inner element. But because "tabscontent" has hidden overflow it only show active page and no scroll bar.

Comment: It is pretty nice, I was just trying to figure out what was going on exactly. But yes, it's like calling `focus()`, it will scroll the element into view

Comment: Great, thank you very much for explanation. Glad you took it seriously.